# Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{I_{k+1}}{k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Calculate $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{I_{k+1}}{k}$ with I$_{n}$ = $\int_{0}^{1}x^{n}e^{x}dx$ .

Any help or other methods. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interchanging the order of summation and integration (unproblematic, since everything is non-negative), we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{I_{k+1}}{k} = \int_0^1 xe^x\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k}\,dx = -\int_0^1 xe^x\log (1-x)\,dx.$$

Now integrating by parts is feasible,

$$-\int_0^1 xe^x\log (1-x)\,dx = \left[(1-x)e^x\log(1-x)\right]_0^1 + \int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1-x}e^x\,dx.$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#00f}{\large\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{1 \over k}\,
\int_{0}^{1}x^{k + 1}\expo{x}\,\dd x}
&=\int_{0}^{1}\expo{x}\
\overbrace{\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}{x^{k + 1} \over k}}^{-x\ln\pars{1 - x}}\
\,\dd x
=-\int_{0}^{1}x\ln\pars{1 - x}\expo{x}\,\dd x = \color{#00f}{\Large\expo{} - 1}
\end{align}

> \begin{align}
> &\color{#f00}{-\int_{0}^{1}x\ln\pars{1 - x}\expo{x}\,\dd x}=
> -\int_{x = 0}^{x = 1}\ln\pars{1 - x}\,\dd\bracks{\expo{x}\pars{x - 1}}=
> \int_{x = 0}^{x = 1}\expo{x}\pars{x - 1}\,{-1 \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
> \\[3mm]&=\int_{0}^{1}\expo{x}\,\dd x = \color{#f00}{\expo{} - 1}
> \end{align}